# Error during webpack build with jasmine

Tags: jasmine, angular-cli

My webpack build started failing. The error I'm getting is this:

> asset optimizationError in bail mode: [default]
>   C:\Personal\Development\mum-
>       app\mum-frontend-angular\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:39:37 
>       A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
>       [ERROR] Command execution failed.
>       org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
>         at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>         at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>         at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
>         at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
>         at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
>         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>         at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

I have not changed any of my dependencies, however, some are a bit outdated. I haven't had any problems with the current setup before. My package.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "mum-ngui-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.5",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.40",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.0-beta.18",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.4.0",
    "protractor": "5.0.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.5"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Locking my jasmine version fixed it.

So in your case, try replacing

```
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.40",
```

by

```
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.40",
```

also I think this is the issue itself on the github:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14579